# How to use a dynamic value for StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a combo box that is bound to an a list of objects of type MyObject:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

The string "Template" is a string that should be used with String.Format, i.e. it might contains "{0}" that should be replaced with the string "Parameter".

I would like to display the result in a label without having to add a new field in the viewmodel. I am looking for XAML similar to this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbMyObjects" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjects}"/>
<Label Name="lblDisplay2" Content="{Binding ElementName=cbMyObjects, Path=SelectedItem.Parameter}" ContentStringFormat="{Binding ElementName=cbMyObjects, Path=SelectedItem.Template}" />
```

I.e. if the list has an object such that Template = "Weight: {0}", Parameter = "3kg", the label should display "Weight: 3kg"

Comment: You might be able to override the `ToString()` with `string.Format(this.Template, this.Parameter)`. I am not sure but maybe the binder will try and call `ToString()` to get the string value of the object...

Comment: or add another property `public string FormattedValue => string.Format(Template, Parameter);`

Comment: Those solutions are in c#. I would like as much as possible to separate Model and View-model, so I would prefer a solution in XAML. @MichaelCoxon  I don't like to override ToString since the object have other parameters and I feel like having a ToString method specific to a minority of the fields would be bad design. Plus, I might need the ToString method of this object for other purpose later.

Comment: @Reniuz Also to keep Model and View-model separated (Since the requirement is purely for UI) I would like to avoid having to add a property

Comment: How do you get a display value for the combo if you do not have a ToString?

Comment: @acourchesne that make sense.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon It uses another field that I didn't talk about: `DisplayMemberPath="ID"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but I managed to get it to work using the `ToString()` method I proposed in the comments and with a Property on the `MainWindow` class... all code below...

It looks like the `ToString()` populates the combo box with values and the template that you proposed works for the label.

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel >
            <ComboBox Name="cbMyObjects" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
            <Label Name="lblDisplay2" Content="{Binding ElementName=cbMyObjects, Path=SelectedItem.Parameter}" ContentStringFormat="{Binding ElementName=cbMyObjects, Path=SelectedItem.Template}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0}", Parameter = "asdF1" };
                yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0}", Parameter = "asdF2" };
                yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0}", Parameter = "asdF3" };
                yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0}", Parameter = "asdF4" };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### MyObject.cs

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => string.Format(this.Template, this.Parameter);
}
```

Comment: This works. I will mark this solution as accepted if there is no possible solution only in XAML using the two existing fields

Comment: @acourchesne As per your comment in the question, The `ToString` is not needed as it only populates the Combo box. Try changing it to `public override string ToString() => string.Format(this.Template, this.Parameter) + "121212";` to see what i mean

Answer (score 1):

I took Michael Coxon answer and made a version using a converter to avoid the `ToString()`

Basically, you can solve your problem in a rather generic way using a `MultiBinding` and a `IMultiValueConverter` which is basically a WPF adapter for `string.Format()`

### Xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="SandBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SandBox"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SandBox.Properties"
    Title="{x:Static properties:Resources.TitleSandbox}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ComboBox
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:TemplateConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Template" />
                            <Binding Path="Parameter" />
                            <Binding Path="Double" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

### ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0} with double value of {1:F2}", Parameter = "asdF1", Double = 1.0 / 3.0 };
            yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0} with double value of {1:F2}", Parameter = "asdF2", Double = 4.5 };
            yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0} with double value of {1:F2}", Parameter = "asdF3", Double = 78 };
            yield return new MyObject { Template = "The parameter value is {0} with double value of {1:F2}", Parameter = "asdF4", Double = Double.PositiveInfinity };
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }

    public double Double { get; set; }
}
```

### Converter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Permit {local:TemplateConverter} markup
/// </summary>
public class TemplateConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => new TemplateConverter();
}

public class TemplateConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length >= 1 && values[0] is string template)
        {
            return string.Format(template, values.Skip(1).ToArray());
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Give at least a template");

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException("Todo, eventually");
}
```

### Sample:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Why not override `ToString()` to do what you want on `MyObject`

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format(this.Template, this.Parameter); 
}
```

Then if you bind to SelectedItem, the `ToString()` method will be called under the hood.

Comment: "Then in your content you can just call SelectedItem.ToString()" : xaml doesn't support method calls. However `Content="{Binding SelectedItem}"` will call it under the hood

Comment: Thanks for the correction @ASh I'll update my answer now.

Comment: I think this solution could solve my problem, but please see my concerns in a comment on the main question